# Global Weather asmx service

Tags: asp.net

Good evening everyone,I been looking for a weather asmx service recently for asp.net, I searched through the web and found bunch of them but most of them are not working such as (webserviceX is not working since 2 weeks) or other services are very weak, thus I'm wondering if you know any website that has these kind of services(weather)? thnx in advance! 
P.S. If you curious what the error I get once I run weather service of WebserviceX : **System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk**

Comment: not asmx but definitely usable in .net https://developer.forecast.io/

Comment: thnx you for the source mr. @fox